# Is there an equivalent of C#'s Path.GetExtension in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, filepath

I want to get the extension of a file path in Flex. In C# I would just use Path.GetExtension() to do this.

Is there an equivalent in Flex, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Flex app running in AIR? If yes, you can:

```
            var file:File = new File("c:\\myfile.bat");
            trace(file.extension);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not using AIR. :(

Comment: In this case not...I suppose you are using FileReference for upload/download, and they have the extension property only for AIR.